# cannot modify the design of table it is in a read-only database

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to export data into excel sheet i have written code but getting error i dont know where i am wrong please help

It is showing error "cannot modify the design of table it is in a read-only database "

```
      public override void ExportToExcel()
       {
        MModule objModule = new MModule();
        objModule.LoadModule(this.Data.MID);

        DatabaseObject objData = new DatabaseObject();

        string file = DateTime.Now.Ticks + "_" + objModule.Title + ".xlsx";
        System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("/Excel/Export/template.xlsx"),   
        Server.MapPath("/Excel/Export/" + file));
        string filename = Server.MapPath("/Excel/Export/" + file);
        objData.Query = "SELECT * FROM " + objModule.TableName + "";
        DataTable dtReport = objData.GetTable();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new 
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
        Source=" + filename + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 
        Xml;HDR=YES\"");

        con.Open();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        string tableString = "";
        string ColString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dtReport.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            tableString += "[" + dtReport.Columns[i].Caption + "] varchar(255),";
            ColString += "[" + dtReport.Columns[i].Caption + "],";
        }
        tableString = tableString.Substring(0, tableString.Length - 1);
        try
        {
            ColString = ColString.Substring(0, ColString.Length - 1);

            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MySheet (ID char(255), Field1 char(255))";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            string ValString = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dtReport.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                ValString = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < dtReport.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    ValString += "'" + dtReport.Rows[j][i] + "',";
                }
                ValString = ValString.Substring(0, ValString.Length - 1);
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into " + objModule.Title + "(" + ColString + 
                ") Values (" + ValString + ");";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
            con.Close();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication = new 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = 
            excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filename,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1]).Delete();
            workbook.Close(true, filename, null);
            excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: why are you creating a table in the database?